# Keras: model definition in a loop: 'list' object has no attibute

Tags: python, keras

I have a strong suspicion there is a better way of setting this up, and suggestions are welcome, but here I am:

I would like to do multi-class classification of time-series data using a recurrent neural network in Keras. My model definition goes like this:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(out_dim, input_shape = (X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2]), return_sequences = False))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='sigmoid'))

optim_type = ["rmsprop", "adam", "sgd"]
  for optim_val in optim_type:
            if optim_val == "sgd" and default_val == False:
                   ...
            else:
                    optim_use = optim_type
            model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer = optim_use, metrics = ['accuracy'])
            hist = model.fit(X_train, dummy_y, validation_data=(X_test, dummy_y_test), nb_epoch = epochs, batch_size = b_size)
```

The error I get is:

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../rnn_new.py", line 213, in <module>
    network_LSTM_rnn(data_in, out_dim, optim_type, b_size, save_file, num_classes, epochs, default_val)
  File "../rnn_new.py", line 166, in network_LSTM_rnn
    hist = model.fit(X_train, dummy_y, validation_data=(X_test, dummy_y_test), nb_epoch = epochs, batch_size = b_size)
  File "/user/pkgs/anaconda2/envs/my_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/models.py", line 627, in fit
    sample_weight=sample_weight)
  File "/user/pkgs/anaconda2/envs/my_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1097, in fit
    self._make_train_function()
  File "/user/pkgs/anaconda2/envs/my_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 712, in _make_train_function
    training_updates = self.optimizer.get_updates(self._collected_trainable_weights,
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get_updates'
```

How can I fix this error? Is there anything else you need me to post?

Comment: `optim_use` seems to be a list instead of being a datatype of `keras.optimizers` class. Can you paste here the output of the following command: `type(optim_use)`?

Comment: <type 'list'> but why is it type 'list'? Hold on I have some edits...

Answer (score 0):

I just can't name variables. Where I have optim_use = optim_type I should have optim_use = optim_val. Thank you anyway!